# Conversion error in VS 2010

Tags: .net-4.0

I have a web application in VS 2003 (1.1) that i need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 and target to framework 4.0. But it showing the error like

> "Internal MSBuild Error: Setting property without a project and without a pending global properties collection."

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and the only thing wrong was that something in the folder was reaonly.  Make everything writable and try again.

Comment: Correct answer, had the same problem and unselecting the readonly fixed it.